# Множество горизонтальных линий в mplfinance

Tags: python

Прошу помощи, ибо не могу понять в чём ошибка.
Есть график, на неём нужно построить 2 горизонтальных линии, но почему-то сталкиваюсь с ошикой validatora
Код:

```
    df.set_index("Time", inplace=True)
    df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)

    mpf.plot(df, type='candle', style='yahoo', title="Stock Price", ylabel='Price',
             alines=dict(alines=[line_1, line_2], colors="r", linestyle="-"))
    mpf.show()
```

Ошибка:

```
TypeError: kwarg "alines" validator returned False for value: "{'alines': [[('189', 0.06682), ('999', 0.06682)], [('191', 0.06954), ('999', 0.06954)]], 'colors': 'r', 'linestyle': '-'}"
    'Validator'   : lambda value: _alines_validator(value) },
```

Опыт не первый уже, и ранее норм создавалось, используется библиотека **mplfinance** но сейчас почему-то не пропускает. Может у меня уже глаз замылился. Прошу помощи.
За ранее, спасибо!
Всем хорошего дня и чистого рабочего кода!